# Find files then tar with wildcard

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I have a series of files called:

```
2014111test.log
2014111test.log.stuff
2014111test.log.flibble
2014115test.log
2014115test.log.stuff
2014115test.log.flibble
```

I want to find all the log files over a certain age, then tar.gz them along with any other file with the same beginning part of the name into an archive.

```
$ find . -name '20*.log' -ctime +90 -exec 'tar zvcf /var/log/logzip/{}.tgz {}*' \;
find: tar zvcf /var/log/fwlogzip/./2014111test.log.tgz ./2014111test.log*: No such file or directory
...
```

However, if I type

```
tar zvcf /var/log/fwlogzip/./2014111test.log.tgz ./2014111test.log*
```

by itself, it works fine.  So it looks like something is going wrong with the globbing as find passes the command to the shell.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try once removing quotes around the tar command and also remove * after { }, why you are using * after { }. I have checked it it is working fine.

Comment: Please read the question again - I am tar-ing multiple files base on the filename found.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have quotes around your tar command? Kill the quotes. You're trying to run the command:

```
tar zvcf /var/log/fwlogzip/./2014111test.log.tgz ./2014111test.log*
```

with no arguments

Remember that UNIX commands can have embedded spaces in it.

I can't test this but:

```
find . -name '20*.log' -ctime +90 -exec tar zvcf /var/log/logzip/{}.tgz {}* \;
```

should work.

Comment: It doesn't.  Did you test it?